# Embedding mathematical equations in an Elm Spa

Tags: elm, katex

I want to put mathematical equations in a single page app written in elm.
I would like the equations to be rendered in the app and not being embedded as prerendered images.

I tried to realize this using Katex for elm (https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/yotamDvir/elm-katex/latest/) but my approach has 3 major problems:

- when the page is loaded initially the equations are not rendered
- the rendering does not always work when a link is clicked
- rendered math elements are preserved in page changes when a link is clicked, thus destroying the content of the page.

This is hoow it looks:
[image: Example of the 3 problems described above]

Here is the code that I am using right now:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>SPA with Math formulas</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #000000;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="main.js"></script>

  <style>
    /* LaTeX display environment will effect the LaTeX characters but not the layout on the page */
    span.katex-display {
      display: inherit;
      /* You may comment this out if you want the default behavior */
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-AfEj0r4/OFrOo5t7NnNe46zW/tFgW6x/bCJG8FqQCEo3+Aro6EYUG4+cU+KJWu/X" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-g7c+Jr9ZivxKLnZTDUhnkOnsh30B4H0rpLUpJ4jAIKs4fnJI+sEnkvrMWph2EDg4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-mll67QQFJfxn0IYznZYonOWZ644AWYC+Pt2cHqMaRhXVrursRwvLnLaebdGIlYNa" crossorigin="anonymous"
    onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
</head>



<body>

  <div id="elm-main"> </div>
  <script>
    // Initialize your Elm program
    var app = Elm.Main.init({
      flags: location.href,
      node: document.getElementById('elm-main')
    });

    // Inform app of browser navigation (the BACK and FORWARD buttons)
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
      app.ports.onUrlChange.send(location.href);
    });

    // Change the URL upon request, inform app of the change.
    app.ports.pushUrl.subscribe(function (url) {
      history.pushState({}, '', url);
      app.ports.onUrlChange.send(location.href);
    });

    // Render math texts in app
    app.ports.renderMath.subscribe(function () {
      renderMathInElement(document.body, {
        delimiters: [
          {
            left: "$begin-inline$",
            right: "$end-inline$",
            display: false
          },
          {
            left: "$begin-display$",
            right: "$end-display$",
            display: true
          }]
      });
    });
  </script>
  <noscript>
    This site needs javascript enabled in order to work.
  </noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

`src/Main.elm`

```
port module Main exposing (..)

import Browser exposing (Document, application)
import Element exposing (Attribute, Element)
import Element.Font
import Html
import Html.Attributes
import Html.Events
import Json.Decode as D
import Katex
import Url
import Url.Parser


main =
    Browser.document
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }


type Route
    = Home
    | Other


init : String -> ( Route, Cmd Msg )
init url =
    ( locationHrefToRoute url, Cmd.none )


type Msg
    = PushUrl Route
    | UrlChanged String


update : Msg -> Route -> ( Route, Cmd Msg )
update msg route =
    case msg of
        PushUrl newRoute ->
            ( route, pushUrl (stringFromRoute newRoute) )

        UrlChanged url ->
            ( locationHrefToRoute url, renderMath () )


stringFromRoute : Route -> String
stringFromRoute route =
    case route of
        Home ->
            "/"

        Other ->
            "/other"


locationHrefToRoute : String -> Route
locationHrefToRoute locationHref =
    case Url.fromString locationHref of
        Nothing ->
            Home

        Just url ->
            Maybe.withDefault Home (Url.Parser.parse routeParser url)


routeParser : Url.Parser.Parser (Route -> a) a
routeParser =
    Url.Parser.oneOf
        [ Url.Parser.map Home Url.Parser.top
        , Url.Parser.map Other (Url.Parser.s "other")
        ]


view : Route -> Document Msg
view route =
    { title = "SPA and Katex"
    , body =
        [ Element.layout
            [ Element.Font.color (Element.rgb 1 1 1)
            ]
            (Element.el
                [ Element.centerX, Element.centerY ]
                (viewPage route)
            )
        ]
    }


viewPage : Route -> Element Msg
viewPage route =
    case route of
        Home ->
            Element.column [ Element.spacing 20 ]
                [ link Other "Link to Other"
                , Element.text "some text"
                , "\\mathrm{home} =  6.2 \\times 10^{-34}"
                    |> Katex.inline
                    |> Katex.print
                    |> Element.text
                ]

        Other ->
            Element.column [ Element.spacing 20 ]
                [ link Home "Link to Home"
                , "\\mathrm{other} = 1.3 \\times 10^{-6}"
                    |> Katex.inline
                    |> Katex.print
                    |> Element.text
                , Element.text "other text"
                ]


linkBehaviour : Route -> Attribute Msg
linkBehaviour route =
    Element.htmlAttribute
        (Html.Events.preventDefaultOn "click"
            (D.succeed
                ( PushUrl route, True )
            )
        )


link : Route -> String -> Element Msg
link route labelText =
    Element.link
        [ linkBehaviour route
        , Element.Font.color (Element.rgb255 119 35 177)
        , Element.Font.underline
        ]
        { url = stringFromRoute route
        , label = Element.text labelText
        }


subscriptions : Route -> Sub Msg
subscriptions route =
    Sub.batch
        [ onUrlChange UrlChanged
        ]


port onUrlChange : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg


port pushUrl : String -> Cmd msg


port renderMath : () -> Cmd msg
```

I start my app with `elm-live src/Main.elm -u --open -- --output=main.js --debug`:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elm-katex docs point out ports being unnecessary.

> No ports are necessary, but the KaTeX library must be loaded in the
> event loop. See §Loading KaTeX at the bottom for details.

The [Loading KaTeX](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/yotamDvir/elm-katex/latest/#loading-katex) section of the docs suggests listening for DOMContentLoaded, then calling KaTeX's auto-render extension. That said, KaTeX's auto-render extension works by editing the DOM, meaning it won't play nice with Elm.

Rendering Tex math using KaTeX is a good use-case for a [Custom Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) (Web Components). It would be relatively straightforward to implement if you're familiar with custom elements but there's likely something already out there that will work.

See the [Custom Elements section of the Elm Guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/custom_elements.html) for a good intro.

I've not taken much of a look at  it, but here's an option: [navsgh/katex-expression](https://github.com/navsgh/katex-expression)

Load *katex-expression* before you initialize your Elm code, then write something like this:

```
import Html exposing (Html, node)
import Html.Attributes exposing (attribute)
import Json.Encode as Encode


viewLatex : String -> Html msg
viewLatex expr =
  node "katex-expression"
    [ attribute "expression" expr
    , attribute "katex-options" (Encode.encode 0 options)
    ]
    []


options : Encode.Value
options =
    Encode.object
        [ ( "displayMode", Encode.bool True )
        ]
```

Here's a quick Ellie demo: https://ellie-app.com/m9HQrnXmydLa1